# Capistrano (3) deploy task updates assets manifest but not application-xyz.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline, sprockets

After a cap deploy the manifest in `shared/public/assets/` gets updated but not the application-xyz.js, although the content of at least one js file changed. Even more curious: The content of the application-xyz.js stays the same based on an older release until this release gets removed. It seems like the wrong js files are used for assets generation but I can't figure out why.

Any idea what might go wrong there?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

**Update:**

As a workaround I force assets to be recompiled during every deployment by adding a *random seed* in assets initializer.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = rand.to_s[0..5]
```

Comment: I got the same issue ... not found yet why ..

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Haven't checked out Bjoernsen's answer. But @erwin you can test my workaround ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a easy solution. https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/102

I added `set :assets_roles, [:web, :app]` to `deploy.rb`.